# Java Android: How to read LOCAL Xml file? (Becoming crazy)

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, local

Im becoming crazy attempting to parse a xml file some like this

I got it , but reading from a URL of a **REMOTE** XML file

There is it,  May be  helpful for this thread or another

LINK TO THE WORKING REMOTE XML PARSING FILEhttp://iatek.eu/flagger/new1.java

But I want to read the XML from R.assets/myxml.xml , or something similar, so, as **LOCAL FILE**.

Here is a part of the XML that I need to read:

```
<menu>
    <item>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Albania</name>
        <pop>3.190.000</pop>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Germany</name>
        <pop>82.244.000</pop>
    </item>
</menu>
```

So the question is that I need to read data from the same XML file locally and Im starting hating javaa! jaja

i have read a lot of stuff about it, ABOUT how the SAX or DOM systems works, bla blah... u have try with a lot of codes and it doesnt work.

That is the last attempt

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try {

        InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.samp); // Here is the problem ...
        DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = null;
        NodeList animals = doc.getElementsByTagName("animal");
        for (int i=0;i<animals.getLength();i++) {

            String a=""+((DocumentBuilderFactory) animals.item(i)).getAttribute("species");
        }
        in.close();
            doc = builder.parse(in, null);
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


}
```

But java found errors that I dont understand , So can seomeone help me to read variables from that xml but LOCALLY? thank you, 
Im desperated i took a lot of time with this without running it

Comment: Please post what the "Java Errors that I don't understand" are, without knowing that those are, it's really hard to answer your question.

Comment: Your code is looking for an animal element and species attribute but there are no such items in the XML you listed. Also I recommend using the Android XMLPullParser.

Comment: There is an example of the last attempt OBVIOUSLY each proyect have its xml documet look the link below